# How is it possible to legally write ::: in C++ and ??? in C#?

Tags: c#, c++, syntax

These questions are a kind of game, and I did not find the solution for them.
It is possible to write `:::` in C++ without using quotes or anything like this and the compiler will accept it (macros are prohibited too).

And the same is true for C# too, but in C#, you have to write `???`.

I think C++ will use the `::` scope operator and C# will use `? :` , but I do not know the answers to them.

Any idea?

Comment: what in the sam hill

Comment: I'm guessing this is a homework question that got put through a word blender.

Comment: These questions were given to us at the beginning of the lecture saying: "if someone already knows this topic, they can work in this question" :)

Comment: He's asking for an admissible C++ program that contains ::: not in a string literal. It's actually a somewhat interesting question, since by the maximum munch principle a ::: on its own will be parsed as :: :, so the ternary operator won't help.
The best I can do is to abuse digraphs:

    const int dim=10;
    int a<:::dim];

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write three consecutive question marks in C# without quotes, but not without whitespace, using the null-coalescing operator and the nullable alias character:

```
object x = 0;
int y = x as int? ?? 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

With whitespace, it's easy:

C++

```
class A{};
class B : :: A{};
```

or

```
int foo;

int bar(){
    return decision ? -1 : :: foo;
}
```

But without whitespace, these won't compile (the compiler sees `:: :`, which doesn't make any sense).

Similarly, [Aaronaught](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503585/how-is-it-possible-to-legally-write-in-c-and-in-c/2504952#2504952) gave a good example of `? ??` in C#, but without whitespace, the compiler sees it as `?? ?`, which won't compile.

Comment: Do you have a reference that C# compiler see `???` as `?? ?` ? It's make more scene that the compiler don't *see* it at all.

Comment: @Mendy:  Without whitespace (`???`), the compiler gives two errors: "Invalid expression term '?'", located at the third question mark, and "; expected" located after it.  If you put a space in so that it's `?? ?`, you get the same two errors at the same [relative] locations.  It's essentially the "maximum munge" principal that user168715 mentioned in a comment to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> I think C# will use ? :
> ```

Do you mean use three question marks in the same line?

> ```
> var a = true ? new Nullable<int>(1) ?? 1 : 0;
> ```

**Edit:** as far as I know, it's impossible to write `???` in any version of C#.